# Anyone know of a full suite of Devise Rspec / Capybara tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, devise, suite

I've been learning Rails 3 with Devise and, so far, seem to have it working quite well. I've got custom session & registration controllers, recaptcha is working and a signed-in user can upload an avatar via carrierwave, which is saved on S3. Pretty happy with my progress.

Now I'm writing Rspec tests. Not going so well! I have a reasonable User model test, but that's because I found it online (https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber/) and was able to add to it by following Michael Hartl's excellent "Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial".

My real problem is controller test and integration tests, especially controller tests. Initially I thought I'd be able to convert the tests in Michael's book, and I have to a small degree, but it's slow progress and I seem to be constantly hitting my head against a brick wall - partly, I think, because I don't know Rspec and capybara so well (have made some very dumb mistakes) but also because I don't really understand Devise well enough and am wondering if Devise plays as nicely as it might with Rspec; I read somewhere that, because Devise is Rack based, it might not always work as one might expect with Rspec. Don't know if that's true or not?

I know some people will wonder why this might be necessary since Devise is a gem and therefore already tested but I've had a couple of instances where changes elsewhere have broken login or registration without me immediately realizing. I think a good set of controller & integration tests would have solved this.

If I was able to do this myself I would and I'd publish it for others but, so far, writing these tests has been extremely painful and I really need to move on to other things.

I'm sure I wouldn't be the only one who could use this. Anyone know of a such a suite of tests?

**In response to Jesse's kind offer of help...**

Here is my registrations_controller_spec. The comments in "should render the 'edit' page" show the sort of things I am struggling with. Also, "should create a user" has some things I've tried to test but not been able to:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'

describe Users::RegistrationsController do
  include Devise::TestHelpers
  fixtures :all
  render_views

  before(:each) do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  end

  describe "POST 'create'" do
    describe "failure" do
      before(:each) do
        @attr = { :email => "", :password => "",
                  :password_confirmation => "", :display_name => "" }
      end

      it "should not create a user" do
        lambda do
          post :create, :user_registration => @attr
        end.should_not change(User, :count)
      end

      it "should render the 'new' page" do
        post :create, :user_registration => @attr
        response.should render_template('new')
      end
    end

    describe "success" do
      before(:each) do
        @attr = { :email => "user@example.com",
                  :password => "foobar01", :password_confirmation => "foobar01", :display_name => "New User" }
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        lambda do
          post :create, :user => @attr
          response.should redirect_to(root_path)
          #response.body.should have_selector('h1', :text => "Sample App")
          #response.should have_css('h1', :text => "Sample App")
          #flash[:success].should == "A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address. Please open the link to activate your account."
          #response.should have_content "A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address. Please open the link to activate your account."
        end.should change(User, :count).by(1)
      end

    end

  end

  describe "PUT 'update'" do
    before(:each) do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      @user.confirm! # or set a confirmed_at inside the factory. Only necessary if you are using the confirmable module
      sign_in @user
    end

    describe "Failure" do

      before(:each) do
        # The following information is valid except for display_name which is too long (max 20 characters)
        @attr = { :email => @user.email, :display_name => "Test", :current_password => @user.password }
      end

      it "should render the 'edit' page" do
        put :update, :id => subject.current_user, :user => @attr

        # HAVE PUT THE DEBUGS THAT I'D LIKE TO GET WORKING FIRST
        # Would like to be able to debug and check I'm getting the error(s) I'm expecting
        puts subject.current_user.errors.messages # doesn't show me the errors
        # Would like to be able to debug what html is being returned:
        puts page.html # only return the first line of html

        # Would like to be able to determine that this test is failing for the right reasons
        response.should have_content "Display name is too long (maximum is 20 characters)" # doesn't work

        response.should render_template('edit')
      end
    end

    describe "Success" do

      it "should change the user's display name" do
        @attr = { :email => @user.email, :display_name => "Test", :current_password => @user.password }
        put :update, :id => subject.current_user, :user => @attr
        subject.current_user.reload
        response.should redirect_to(root_path)
        subject.current_user.display_name == @attr[:display_name]
      end

    end
  end

  describe "authentication of edit/update pages" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do

      before(:each) do
        @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      end

      describe "for non-signed-in users" do

        it "should deny access to 'edit'" do
          get :edit, :id => @user
          response.should redirect_to(new_user_session_path)
        end

        it "should deny access to 'update'" do
          put :update, :id => @user, :user => {}
          response.should redirect_to(new_user_session_path)
        end

      end

    end
  end

end
```

Comment: I think having a signup request spec is a reasonable part of your test suite. Why don't you create a sign-up and sign-in spec, and then post that here. I'll help you with whatever problems you have. I think the reason you're not seeing a full suite anywhere is that the tests themselves end up pretty trivial.

Comment: I have such a spec and that seems to work ok. It's things like registrations_controller_spec that I'm having the most trouble with (it works but not as well I'd like.) Could you help with that?... I'll happily post my sign-up and sign-in spec request if it will help anyone else though?

Comment: Are you overriding the devise controllers? If not, I would stick to request specs that test the entire stack.

Comment: If I'm getting my terminology correct, I'm just inheriting. For example, my registrations_controller includes code to verify recaptcha and my sessions_controller does nothing more than supply an additional @title variable to the view.

Comment: If you'll post a controller spec for registrations controller I'll help diagnose what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so a couple of things to make this work:

Here's how you should test that the body have specific text (you were missing the .body

```
response.body.should include "Display name is too long (maximum is 30 characters)"
```

You could also test that the @user has an error:

```
assigns[:user].errors[:display_name].should include "is too long (maximum is 30 characters)"
```

But, you do need to actually make the name be over 20/30 characters long, so I changed the attributes being posted to:

```
@attr = { :email => @user.email, :display_name => ("t" * 35), :current_password => @user.password }
```

https://gist.github.com/64151078628663aa7577

Answer (score 1):

Acording to [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/), controller tests have to be some kind of hibrid (unit + integration) tests. You have to create an instance of User (or you auth entity) in the database. Mocking Devise stuff is really hard, trust me.

Try this: [How-To:-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-and-rspec](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29)

With Cucumber, you can create a step that already do the login process.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah have already tried the page you have linked to and, although it helped, I still can't get things to work as I would expect. Maybe Cucumber is the way forward! Glad to know it's not just me who finds some of the Devise stuff hard though. Thanks!